# why AbstractList,AbstractSet make abstract not interface

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

While studying the abstract class and interface. I do like to know about why java collection have all classes abstract. Why they don't implement interface instead of abstract class. my question with AbstractList,AbstractSet. why they dont make them interface.

Note::-I need design prospective answer

Comment: You mean like the `List`, `Collection`, `Map` interfaces?

Comment: `Collection` is an interface http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html

Comment: `why java collection have all class abstract.` I don't see it.. :(

Comment: @Kent sorry but my question with abstractList,AbstractSet. why java architech. dont use interface instead of abstract class.

Comment: Because those abstract classes have implemented methods. interfaces don't allow that. @RakhiSsdd

Comment: You are mistaken. It has abstract classes *and* interfaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I do like to know about why java collection have all class abstract.

That assumption is wrong as you have interfaces like Collection, List and Set ... in Collections framework.

> why they dont implement interface instead of abstract class.

If you mean `AbstractList,AbstractSet` ..etc, because to provide basic implementations which is not possible with interfaces (below java8)

And finally combining your both points you can see

```
AbstractList implements Iterable<E>, Collection<E>, List<E> {}
```

Answer (score 2):

`List`, `Collection`, `Map`, and `Set` are all interfaces. If you are talking about any of the `AbstractList`, `AbstractCollection`, `AbstractMap`, or `AbstractSet`, all you need to do is look at the Javadoc for those to see why they were implemented.

Example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html

```
public abstract class AbstractSet<E>
extends AbstractCollection<E>
implements Set<E>
```

> This class provides a skeletal implementation of the Set interface to
>   minimize the effort required to implement this interface. The process
>   of implementing a set by extending this class is identical to that of
>   implementing a Collection by extending AbstractCollection, except that
>   all of the methods and constructors in subclasses of this class must
>   obey the additional constraints imposed by the Set interface (for
>   instance, the add method must not permit addition of multiple
>   instances of an object to a set).
>
> Note that this class does not override any of the implementations from
>   the AbstractCollection class. It merely adds implementations for
>   equals and hashCode.

Answer (score 1):

Most java collections do both, implement an interface and extend an abstract class.

eg:

- HashMap and TreeMap extend AbstractMap which implements Map
- ArrayList and LinkedList extend AbstractList which implements List
- HashSet and TreeSet extend AbstractSet which implements Set

In your code, you should declare your variables as the interface where possible. eg:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The Collections framework has Interfaces like `List`, `Map` , `Set` etc.

Then there are abstract classes which implement the interfaces and define / implement methods which are used *commonly* across all the concrete implementations. examples : `AbstractList`, `AbstractSet`, `AbstractMap`.

Then you add additional functionality to the concrete collection classes like `ArrayList` , `HashMap`, `HashSet` which extend these Abstract Classes.